# Multiple Email Alert in Windows Phone 8

Tags: email, alert

I have a Windows Phone 8 with two mails configured in it. One is a critical mail account which I need to know when ever it alerts. Other one is not that critical but need alert too.

I would like to have seperate alerting sounds so that I could identify which email box has just recieved the email.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple visual notifications but not sound notifications.

There is only one master configuration for email sounds.